# Comparing a int[] and a String to check if numbers are in the right sequence and if they have any same number in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, compare

I am trying to compare a method that creates random numbers and adds them to an int[], with the user input which is saved as a String.
The code for the random number generator is this

```
int[] x = {0, 0, 0, 0};
boolean isDuplicate = false;
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        if (x[j] == y) {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isDuplicate) {
        i--;
        isDuplicate = false;
    } else {
        x[i] = y;
    }
}
//Stores a representation of the int[] array to the String y and returns it.
String y = Arrays.toString(x);
return y;
```

So my question is how do I compare the int[] and the user input String to see if they contain any same numbers and then check to see if any of the numbers are in the same order
i.e
Say that i have variable checkNumber and checkSequence
If I have

```
int[] = { 3, 5, 6, 1}
String userinput= "1,5,9,7"
```

I would want to get checkNumber = 2; and checkSequence = 1;

I then want to add them in an ArrayList, so seeing as an ArrayList cannot contain primitive types like int but does accept Strings, how would I convert the int[] to a String and then compare it to my other String?

Comment: It's actually better to convert the string to an int[], then compare them.

Comment: `ArrayList` can't hold primitives correct, but it can be `ArrayList<Integer>` instead, don't convert `int` to `String` to put it in a list.  You can just use an array here though, you don't need to convert it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to `split` by a comma, and convert the resulting `String` array to an `int` array (`createArr()` is the code you provided for generating the array but changed to return an `int` array instead of a `String`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //Create the int array
        int [] arr1 = createArr();
        String userInput = "1,5,9,7";
        
        //Split the String by comma to create an array of String
        String [] strArr = userInput.split(",");
        
        int [] arr2 = new int[strArr.length];

        //Convert String array to int array
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            arr2[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]);
        }
        
        compareArrays(arr1, arr2);
    }
```

You can see in the above code a `split(",")` call on the `userInput`, which you then iterate over with a `for` loop filling in the values of the second `int` array.

Here is the `createArr` method you made slightly altered to `return` the `int` array:

```
public static int[] createArr() {
    int[] x = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    boolean isDuplicate = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         int y = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;
           for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
             if (x[j] == y) {
                isDuplicate = true;
                 break;
              }
         }
         if (isDuplicate) {
        i--;
        isDuplicate = false;
         } else {
            x[i] = y;
        }
    }
    return x;  
}
```

Then you can make a method to compare them such as:

```
public static void compareArrays(int [] arr1, int [] arr2) {
    int checkNumber = 0, checkSequence = 0;
    
    //TODO: For loops to compare the arrays
    
    //Print out the results
    System.out.println("Array 1: " + Arrays.toString(arr1));
    System.out.println("Array 2: " + Arrays.toString(arr2));
    System.out.println("checkNumber: " + checkNumber);
    System.out.println("checkSequence: " + checkSequence);
}
```

I left out the code for the compare loops so you could work that part yourself (hint you can use a nested `for` loop).

Test Run (with compare logic done):

```
Array 1: [3, 5, 7, 2]
Array 2: [1, 5, 9, 7]
checkNumber: 2
checkSequence: 1
```

Note:  Splitting and converting to an `int` array is simpler with streams, but I thought that would be out of scope of this question.

Comment: It's better not to hard-code the array length `int [] arr2 = new int[4];`

Comment: @Alexander Ivanchenko True, fixed it to set it from the `String` array length